# How to remote control Youtube from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, remote-desktop, youtube, remote-control

I tried Chrome Remote Desktop but it's very difficult to use, specially because the Windows screen resolution is much higher than the phone's and it has a different orientation.

I remember Android used to have an app called Youtube Remote and I believe this functionality has been integrated into the main Youtube app, but it doesn't remote control Windows, only TVs.

Is there anything similar to the old Youtube Remote for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your PC/Mac, go to http://youtube.com/tv  (that's not your usual URL, it's the "Lean Back" mode)
2. Go to settings -> Pair a Device (on the sidebar, on the PC)
3. Once instructed to do so, go to your phone and just navigate to http://youtube.com/pair ... if you have the YouTube app, it will ask if you want to open on that app, say yes - if you don't - just move forward
4. Put the pair code from your PC into the pair box on the phone

Presto - you're driving from your phone.

Essentially, "Lean Back" mode treats your PC like a TV, that's why it works.

Comment: Not working. The url http://youtube.com/tv is no more available.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted solution didn't work for me. As a workaround I used VLC to play youtube videos and VLC Remote to control it from mobile devices.